# ui-gmap-markers and icon changeble for all mark

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, angular-ui, angular-google-maps

I am trying to change icon for every markers on a map using ui-google-maps library for angular. `$scope.map.options.icon` working but initialize icon for all markers.

For the API I have icon tags but not working or somewhere I miss something.

```
<ui-gmap-markers 
    idKey="map.dynamicMarkers.id" models="map.dynamicMarkers" 
    coords="'self'" onMarkerClicked="'onMarkerClicked'"
    fit="'true'" doCluster="'true'" clusterEvents="clusterEvents"
    options="map.options" icon="'icon'">
</ui-gmap-markers>
```

and after get data in the database fill list of markers in the dynamicMarkers object list

```
  dynamicMarkers = $scope.allTrees;
  $scope.map.options.icon = "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_green.png";

  _.each(dynamicMarkers, function (marker) {
      if (marker.status == 0) {
        marker.icon = "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_red.png";
      } else if (marker.status == 1) {
        marker.icon = "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_green.png";
      } else if (marker.status == 2) {
        marker.icon = "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_yellow.png";
      }
  });

  $scope.map.dynamicMarkers = dynamicMarkers;
```

For some reason icon not change. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found solution! First need only set icon url on `marker.icon` place and **not set default icon** on `map.options.icon`.
If you set default icon in `map.options` and after try to set icon inside the marker that will not work!

Here is the working example:

```
<ui-gmap-markers 
    idKey="map.dynamicMarkers.id" models="map.dynamicMarkers" 
    coords="'self'" onMarkerClicked="'onMarkerClicked'"
    fit="'true'" doCluster="'true'" clusterEvents="clusterEvents"
    options="map.options" icon="'icon'">
</ui-gmap-markers>
```

angular code

```
dynamicMarkers = $scope.allTrees;
// not set default icon for the mark
// $scope.map.options.icon = "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_green.png";

  _.each(dynamicMarkers, function (marker) {
      if (marker.status == 0) {
        marker.icon = "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_red.png";
      } else if (marker.status == 1) {
        marker.icon = "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_green.png";
      } else if (marker.status == 2) {
        marker.icon = "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_yellow.png";
      }
  });

$scope.map.dynamicMarkers = dynamicMarkers;
```

It is a catch and works. I hope they fix the bug in the next version of angular-google-maps library. I try with angular-google-maps 2.1.5. Chears.